# Solving the GCD m = 735, n =252

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, euclidean-algorithm

I understand everything except the values in $s_i$ and $t_i$ how do we get those values??? Can anyone please elaborate. I have no idea what the formula is for calculating the values in $s_i$ and $t_i$.. 
[image: Find the GCD of m = 735, n =252 . GCD(m,n) = sm + tn]

Comment: See [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)

Comment: Bill I read your explanation. It's great but I mean what is the trick for getting the $s_i$ and $t_i$ is there a trick? Or are you just supposed to guess what numbers to solve the equation?

Comment: The point is that we want to continually keep track of how the $\, r_i\,$ can be expressed as  a linear combination of $735$ and $252$. In your notation this is the equation $\  r_i = 735\, s_i + 252\, t_i.\ $ I highlight this by explicitly writing the equations in the linked answer.

Comment: As I explain there, you can view the *extended* algorithm as the euclidean algorithm extended to the entire equation, i.e. instead of performing the Euclidean operations on the $\,r_i,\,$ you do it on the whole equation $\, r_i = a s_i + b t_i\,$  or, equivalently, on their coefficients = row $\,[r_i, s_i, t_i]\ \ $

Comment: I understand that Bill, I'm just trying to grasp how I am supposed to just GUESS that -31 * something will give me my equation on the left. I mean especially if I have HUGE numbers, luckily this problem was FAIRLY easy to guess. But I mean $-36$ as a $s_i$ value just seems kind of crazy to guess. I mean I started off by making a list of $m$ and multiplying by 2, then 3, then 4.. etc .. See my dilemma? Am i missing the point?

Comment: You know, suppose I have $124,567 = n(34567) + (23456)m$ , how in the hell am I going to just guess that? I mean i'm just going to have to brute force it out right?

Comment: Please point to a specific line in your example or mine and tell me which numbers you don't know how to compute.

Comment: For example, in **your** example, you have $2 = 7(80) - 9(62)$ which means yours $s_i = 7$ and your $t_i = -9$. Are you just that good at solving equations or is there a special formula or trick you used to **obtain** those two values. I could of got those but it would of took me at least 20 minutes of trial and error just plugging in numbers to guess what would turn out to satisfy our linear equation $=2$ ... Does that make sense? Like I would have never have guessed those numbers to solve the equation is what I'm saying. Do I just need to get better at math? Or is there a **shortcut**?

Comment: As notated on the left, that 5th row is simply the result of the following linear combination of the prior two rows: $\,{\rm row}_5 = {\rm row}_3 \color{#c00}{- 2}\ {\rm row}_4,\,$ i.e below, where $\,a,b = 80,62\,$ there
$\tag*{}$
$\qquad \begin{align}
18 =&\quad\ \  1\cdot a - 1\cdot b\qquad \rm row_3\\
\color{#c00}{-2}\,(8 =&\, -3\cdot a + 4\cdot b)\qquad\!\! \rm row_4\\
\Rightarrow\ 2 =&\quad \ \  7\cdot a + 9 \cdot b\qquad \rm row_5
\end{align}$
 $\tag*{}$

Comment: Oops, that should be $\,-9\cdot b\,$ above.

Comment: Bill I finally understand it. My god I don't why that was so hard to wrap my head around. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Great! Please let me know what was unclear so I can improve the exposition.

Comment: Your rows are messed up in your explanation on the other page you are saying row 2 is the very bottom row and row 1 is aboev it??

Comment: row1 is the first (top) row. row2 is the row immediately below row1, etc.

Comment: I get it now. Here is what I was struggling with - the fact that $t_2 = s_1-(q_1*t_1)$ similarly, $s_2 = t_1 - (q_1*s_1)$

Comment: When I teach this I always teach the equations version first, since then it is clearer what scaling and adding equations means. The row operations are not as intuitive to someone who has not yet met them in linear algebra. Unfortunately it is often taught as a rote tabular algorithm with no explanation of what the tables mean. It is best to think of it as the Euclidean algorithm with the remainders annotated by equations giving their linear reps. Any operation you perform on a remainder must also be extended also to their linear reps in order to propagate the reps to every remainder.

Comment: here is what I was looking for: $s_i = s_{i-2} - (s_{i-1} * q_{i-1})$

Comment: I thought you knew that already. Again, it's easier using entire rows than the individual entries. Write the $i$'th row as $\ R_i = [r_i, s_i, t_i].\ $   Then  the row recursion is $\ R_{i+1}= R_{i-1}-q_{i} R_{i}.\,$ And its even clearer when the rows are written in equation form $\ \, r_i = a s_i + b t_i\ $ vs.$\ [r_i, s_i, t_i].\ $